# Couchbase N1QL: How to get complete Document including ID and CAS with SELECT

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am using Couchbase 4.0 beta with java-client 2.1.3.

The `Bucket.get(id)` returns `JsonDocument` from which I can get `id` and `cas` as well as the content. Now I want to query on secondary indices using `N1QL (select *)`. However, the `QueryResult` only returns rows of `JsonObject`s which are just the document contents. Is there anyway I can get the meta data (`id` and `cas`) too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT b, meta(b) AS meta FROM my_bucket b;
```

Comment: is there a way to get the id field directly using the get call? I think there is an extra overhead of going through the query service if you use SELECT query statement